# Restrict the audio playback for only certain duration of time using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have a use-case where I need to play an audio on clicking an element. The audio is playing fine but its duration is a little longer than I thought. I would want it to pause(stop) after certain seconds. I could alert the duration time and I also tried applying stop and/or pause methods both of which didn't work. Any thoughts on this? I am pretty sure some of you might have come across a situation like this. Here is my code.

**jQuery**

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sound/crack.mp3');

        $('#thanksBanner').click(function() {
        audioElement.play();
        });
        audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(_event) {
        var duration = audioElement.duration;
        //TODO whatever
        var ourDuration = duration - 1.5;
        if (duration > ourDuration) {
           audioElement.pause();
           alert(duration);
        };
    });
```

Comment: Why you use `"loadedmetadata"` event? It's not for your case. You have to check duration in `setInterval` (or `setTimeout`) callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate) event which is fired whenever the current playback position has changed. And check that position inside event handler.

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sound/crack.mp3');

$('#thanksBanner').click(function() {
    audioElement.play();
    setInterval(function() {
});
audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    var t = audioElement.currentTime;
    if (t > audioElement.duration - 1.5) {
        audioElement.pause();
        alert(t); //can be removed once it works.
    }
};
```